# Use get_queryset method with tables2

Tags: django

Right now, this code works to render my template as an html table, but I would like to render it as tables2. How to do that, while keeping the "get_queryset" bit in the views.py file is giving me trouble.

urls.py

`path('proforma/<int:pk>/', ProformaDetailView.as_view(), name='proforma-detail')`

views.py

```
class ProformaDetailView(ListView):
    
    template_name = "blog/proforma_detail.html"
    context_object_name = 'proforma'
    
  
    def get_queryset(self):
       
        queryset = Proforma.objects.filter(proforma_id=self.kwargs['pk'])       
        return queryset
```

tables.py | Not currently being used

```
class ProformaDetailTable(tables.Table):    
            
    class Meta:
        model = Proforma
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ('proforma_id','time_stamp','base_price','lot_cost','permit_cost','hard_cost')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [**`SingleTableView`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#singletableview) is a `ListView` with some extra logic to render the table. You thus can implement this as:

```
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView

class ProformaDetailView(SingleTableView):
    table_class = ProformaDetailTable
    template_name = 'blog/proforma_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'proforma'
  
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Proforma.objects.filter(
            proforma_id=self.kwargs['pk']
        )
```

In the template, you can then `{% render table %}`:

```
<!-- blog/proforma_detail.html -->
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
…
{% render_table table %}
```